# What is 'Damage Armor?'

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

In previous games, armor had durability and effects that caused damage to armor affected the armor's durability. After looking at the [Marked For Death](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Marked_for_Death) shout, I noticed the effect included 'Damage Armor.' What exactly does this do? Is it simply an AR reduction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an armour reduction that takes effect over time (every second for the full 60 second duration) and also stacks with itself. This is a permanent reduction which will increase your target's damage from physical attacks and it [works as follows](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Marked_For_Death);

- One word: -25 armour per second up to -1500 armour after 60 seconds
- Two words: -50 armour per second up to -3000 armour after 60 seconds
- Three words: -75 armour per second up to -4500 armour after 60 seconds

This can be repeatedly stacked on an opponent, so shouting three words at an opponent twice will reduce their armour by -9000 after 60 seconds. Additionally, armour values can go into the negatives in Skyrim, further reducing the effectiveness of your opponents armour.

It is possible to hit allies with this ability, and doing so will make them notably less resilient to physical damage for the rest of the game.